# :after position: fixed syntax

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a line in my CSS using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-element. I wanted to make it appear higher/lower with `position : absoute`, and the top and bottom syntax. I applied it succesfully to the `:before` pseudo-element with the bottom syntax, but when i tried to use the top syntax to `:after`, the line disappeared. Here is my code (the div class is 'transition') :

```
.transition:before {
    content : "";
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12.5%;
    bottom: 18%;
    width   : 75%;
    border-bottom:2px solid slategray;
}

.transition:after {
    content : "";
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12.5%;
    top: 18%;
    width   : 75%;
    border-bottom:2px solid slategray;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add full html and css codes

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal I have put the CSS Codes, but not the full one and HTML codes simply because it is very long, and i don't know yet whether it will help you guys solve my problem.

Comment: Provide CSS for .transition element, at least, because, problem can't be recreated with current CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/4qbr05pa/

Comment: It's good to be aware that your original markup is too long for SO—if that's the case, you should reduce your example into a minimal, verifiable and concrete example that can reproduce your issue while only keeping the necessary parts to reproduce the issue.

Comment: not full html code. even if you have 15 div you need to put only relevant one. one which contains the element in question

Comment: @Hafiz The problem can't be recreated because it looks like this https://snag.gy/p1EXTB.jpg 

Post the html of transition div.

Comment: css is fine, must be something else. I also tried and it does what's expected. if we're to go further we'll need more info. please provide the .transition css

https://jsfiddle.net/HUN73R_13/5u0mwpdw/2/

Comment: You might forget to put position:relative to parent element